# Logging json posts with resteasy

Tags: json, post, logging, resteasy

I'm looking for a way to log JSON posts in a RESTEASY framework.

I woul like to log the POST body to log file to see what the client is sending to me.

Is there any interceptor or something similar that I can use, I have found an example for PreProcessInterceptor but it looks like it is deprecated.

I'm using resteasy 3.0.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html):

```
@Provider
public class LogFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        if (!"POST".equals(requestContext.getMethod()) 
                || !MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(requestContext.getMediaType())
                || requestContext.getEntityStream() == null) {
            return;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(requestContext.getEntityStream(), baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        LOG.info("Posted: " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
        requestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

    }

}
```

Instead of checking for Method and Content-Type you can also register this filter per [@NameBinding](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) only where you need it.

**Note:** This simple example copies the InputStream of the request so it will be read twice (maybe a performance problem).

Answer (score 2):

As supplement of excellent answer of lefloh, I suggest replace:

```
!MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(requestContext.getMediaType())
```

with

```
!MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.isCompatible(requestContext.getMediaType())
```

[equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method takes into account parameters of media type, eg. charset=UTF-8,
and does not work in some scenarios according to intention of lefloh.
[isCompatible](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#isCompatible-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-) compares only type and subtype of media type and is more suitable in this case.

PS. I know, this post should be placed as comment, but I have no enough level of reputation to do it. I also edited lefloh answer but some php and ios guys rejected it.