# how to see actual body sent from restassured

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, rest-assured

I have created a jax-rs rest api and tested it with rest-assured. All tests are green. Now I am trying to create an html/js front end for it.

My problem is I do not know how my json objects should look like to be accepted by my rest api. Thanks to restassured/jax-rs I never handled request strings. I fill in objects and I get objects, (un)marshaling (json) is invisible.

Is there any way I can see (debug) what strings are created by rest-assured/java and sent over the "wire"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to log the request body you can do:

```
given().log().body(). ..
```

Or if you want to log the response body you can do:

```
.. .then().log().body(). ..
```

See [documentation on logging](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#logging) for more details.

Comment: How to do it in non-BDD way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a RestAssured used, so I can't answer your question directly, but here are some ideas that may help you out.

- I don't know what serializer RestAssured uses under the hood, but Resteasy on Wildfly uses Jackson by default. I would get familiar with this library. For less trivial application, you may need to dig into its APIs directly to get your desired results. Here is it's [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation). For your particular case you can do something as simple as

  ```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
  System.out.println(jsonString);
  ```

  This will print out the POJO in JSON format, based on your getters in the class. This is at the most basic level. If you don't already have Jackson as a dependency, you can add

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- A really good friend (tool) to have is [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). It's a command line tool that allows you to make REST/HTTP (other protocols also) requests. Though for this particular case it wouldn't help, you could send a GET request to one your resources that serves up the same type that you accepted in your POST. That way, you can see the resulting JSON. This may be a little much at this point, but I would definitely look into this tool if you're going to be doing a lot of REST development.
- You might also want to check out a Browser tool like [Postman for Chrome]
- You should really get familiar with [JSON format](http://json.org/). Once you get familiar with it, and you start working with JSON framework, you'll notice that at a basic level, they all work similarly.

  ```
  Java Object == JSON Object ( {} )
  Java Collection/Array == JSON Array ( [] )
  Java fields/properties == JSON keys

  Getters are used for they keys and their values (for serialization)
  Setters are used for deserialization
  ```

  So for example you have this class

  ```
  public class Person {
      String name;
      List<Person> friends;

      public String getName() { return name; }
      public void setName(String name) { return name; }
      // Getter and Setter for friends
  }
  ```

  An instance of `Person` would produce the following JSON

  ```
  {
      "name" : "Peeskillet",
      "friends": [
          {
              "name": "Lebron James"
          },
          {
              "name": "Steph Curry"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

It's actually pretty simple once you get the hang of it.

- Oh and another thing you can do is add a logging filter on the server side [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191398/2587435).

As far as working with Javascript, there is a `JSON.stringify(javascriptObject)` that will serialize your Javacript objects to JSON strings. So generally, you can model your Javascript object like your Java objects.

Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks for this in depth answe! the first part helped most (i already added jackson dependency for test) - so i use you code example to convert the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In RestAssured just use this:

`String body = resp.asString();
 System.out.println(body);`

Comment: I think author wanted solution for request, not response

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Request Body

```
 RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given().urlEncodingEnabled(true);
..
..
..    
System.out.println(" Body ==> "+ httpRequest.log().body());
```

And for response body:

System.out.println("Res Body ===>"+ response.getBody().prettyPrint());