# Retrieve the entity in Resteasy PreProcessInterceptor

Tags: rest, jax-rs, httprequest, resteasy, interceptor

I am using the resteasy `PreProcessInterceptor` for logging the request and could not find a way to get hold of the `entity` or the `json` object in a `POST` request. Is it possible to get the entity or the `json` object at this level?
I am using Resteasy 2.3.6

Comment: Here's an [example using a ContainerRequestFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191398).

Comment: @lefloh thanks, but I am using resteasy 2.3.6 and the ContainerRequestFilter is not available.

Comment: The code is quite similar. I added a modified example.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the posted entity from `request.getInputStream()` but note that an `InputStream` can't be read twice. An easy (but maybe not the most performant) way is to copy the `InputStream`:

```java
@Provider
public class LoggingInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        if ("POST".equals(request.getHttpMethod()) && request.getInputStream() != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream(), baos);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                LOG.info("Posted: " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
                request.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(ex);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

If you are using Resteasy 3.x you should [use a ContainerRequestFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191398).